# Does anybody know a way to make a video game in turbo c where you have an A moving around on the screen?

Tags: c, bgi

I am trying to make a game with ms-dos called find the key.

What i am struggling with is using graphics.h to move an ASCII character move over a red screen using keyboard input.

Here is a snippet of my source code:

```
if (cn == 1) {
initgraph(&gd, &gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");
settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,3);
setbkcolor(RED);
setcolor(BLACK);
outtextxy(100+i,100,"a");
while (getch() != '\033') { // if the first value is esc
    getch(); // skip the [
    switch(getch()) { // the real value
    case 'D':
        moveleft();
    case 'A':
        // code for arrow down
        break;
    case 'W':
        // code for arrow right
        break;
    case 'S':
        // code for arrow left
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the moveleft() Function:

```
void moveleft() {
int i;


int j;
for( i = 0 ; i <= 420 ; i = i + 10, j++ ){
outtextxy(100+i,100,"a");
setcolor(j);
delay(100);
if( i == 420 )
break;
if ( j == 15 )
j = 2;
cleardevice(); // clear screen
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then read "[ask]" and come back to [edit] your post. -- Unfortunately it is far too broad and includes multiple questions. Please choose one specific question and post new questions for the others.

Comment: https://galdin.dev/blog/why-you-shouldnt-be-using-turbo-c/